# How to download a file from firebase storage and show progress with a content Uri in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-file

I use this code to download a file from firebase storage:

```
private fun downloadFile(url: String, file: File){
    storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url).getFile(file).addOnProgressListener { 
        //TODO: update progess
    }.addOnSuccessListener { 
        //TODO: update ui
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        //TODO: show error message
    }
}
```

The getFile() method accepts a file or file uri, but in my case i have a content Uri which returned from the system picker, not a file uri. And I can't use getBytes() method because it must load the entire contents of the file into memory and my files are relatively big, also the getBytes() method doesn't have a progress callback.

Is there a way to convert a content uri into a file uri?

I thought about downloading the file into temporary local file then reading it again and writing it to the content uri, but i believe there's a better way.

Comment: `i have a content Uri which returned from the system picker, not a file uri.` Which action did you use for that?

Comment: @blackapps The system picker through intent.

Comment: Which ACTION_......???? was the question.

Comment: @blackapps ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT